# What does all my images start with the same sequence?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, data-analysis, console.log

Continuing my experiments and my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57519372/fileupload-duplicating-files) (Solved BTW, THANKS!!) i realized that all the images that i upload start with the same sequence:

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/
```

Does anyone knows what is that? my first impression was that it should be somekind of CRC but it has to change with every upladed file

My code is:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="bid_uploadPicture">Subir Imagen</button>
<input type="file" id="file" accept='image/*' style="display:none;" />
```

```
jQuery(function ($) {

            $("#bid_uploadPicture").click(function () {
                event.preventDefault();
                document.getElementById("file").click();

            });

            $("#file").change(function () {
                var fr = new FileReader();
                fr.onload = function (e) {
                    data = new Uint8Array(e.target.result)
                    console.log(e.target.result);
                }
                //fr.readAsArrayBuffer(this.files[0]);
                fr.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
            });
        });
```

Comment: What does CRC stand for? Are all your images of the same type? Could this have to do with [file signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures)?

Comment: CRC is cyclic redundancy check, its a code to verify the integrity of the file and in some cases auto correct it -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check
And yes you are right the sequence /9j/ is the signature of the JPG header

Answer (score 0):

I just give with the answer, im posting here in case some one else has the same interest

It turns out that this sequence is the JPG signature and the format structure of the uploaded picture as explained in this wikipedia article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format

Regards!!!